# What does "bipartisan support" mean in the United States?

Tags: united-states, congress, parties, terminology

Is there a definition of "bipartisan support"? For the Senate in the US, when can you claim a bill was supported/passed by bipartisanship, and when you can't claim thus?

Comment: Might this be better on [english.se] because it’s asking about word usage?

Comment: I think it is more of a political language than plain English language. Also it is political-centric, Don't you agree?

Comment: There's a definition of this on an online dictionary ...

Comment: @divibisan: The question is tagged united-states. The general term is already fairly specific to countries with a Westminster-style government, but that does include a large swath of English-speaking countries. The specific US interpretation however is more narrow, as is seen in Jontia's answer.

Comment: @MoziburUllah: if only politicians used words exactly as prescribed in dictionaries... https://time.com/4743660/donald-trump-dictionary-words-poll-merriam-webster/

Comment: @MoziburUllah: also one can write very "posh" dictionaries for a (politically minded) reason https://www.jstor.org/stable/3508757

Answer (score 44):

This is entirely dependent on the speaker. But in general senior politicians who have passed legislation are happy to call it Bipartisan on the basis on a single vote.

Nancy Pelosi claimed to have 275 Bipartisan bills that had passed the house prior to 2019, but been ignored by the Republican controlled senate.

[FactCheck.org](https://www.factcheck.org/2019/12/pelosis-bipartisanship-boast/) looked into this claim and found large numbers had fewer than 10 republican votes.

> H.R. 1644, Save the Internet Act: 1 yea, 190 nays.
> H.R. 2722, SAFE Act: 1 yea, 184 nays.
> H.R. 582, Raise the Wage Act: 3 yeas, 192 nays.
> H.R. 9, Climate Action Now: 3 yeas, 190 nays.
> H.R. 7, Paycheck Fairness Act: 7 yeas, 187 nays.
> H.R. 6, American Dream and Promise Act: 7 yeas, 187 nays.
> H.R. 8, Bipartisan Background Checks Act: 8 yeas, 188 nays.
> H.R. 5, Equality Act: 8 yeas, 173 nays.
> H.R. 397, Rehabilitation for Multiemployer Pensions Act (Butch Lewis Act): 29 yeas, 168 nays.
> H.R. 1585, Violence Against Women Reauthorization Act: 33 yeas, 157 nays.

Pelosi's office clarified the single vote requirement when questioned by FactCheck.

> When asked about the “bipartisan bills,” Pelosi’s office sent us a list of 283 “bipartisan bills” with this explanation: “A bill is considered bipartisan if it received at least one Republican vote on the House floor or if it has at least one Republican cosponsor and was passed by voice vote.”

And to be clear this is not a Democrat only issue. The linked article cites similar language from the House leader in 2014. Republican John Boehner.

> In 2014, for example, then-House Speaker John Boehner boasted that “almost all” of the 46 “jobs bills” awaiting action in the Senate “passed the House on a bipartisan basis.” But, as we wrote at the time, half of those bills had fewer than 20 Democratic votes each, including two that received no Democratic votes and 12 others that got 10 or fewer votes each from the opposing party.

Comment: i.e. it's marketing.

Comment: It's trying to distinguish from bills that passed or failed due to everyone just voting the party line.

Comment: Any specific number of votes from the other party is totally arbitrary, so just as much "marketing".

Comment: @JaredSmith it’s a descriptive adjective. I’m not sure how it’s any more or less “marketing” than any other term you could use to describe legislation

Comment: @divibisan I mean marketing as in "saying things that are technically true but sound better than they necessarily are". And I'm not hating, that's just how the game is played.

Comment: @Barmar: Well, you could say something like "the bill received a majority of the minority party's votes" or "the bill was supported by the leader of the minority party in each chamber." I would be perfectly happy to call *those* bills "bipartisan."

Comment: @Kevin I'd say the honest layperson should use the word based on their idea of what "the party" wants, rather than relying on a hard line drawn somewhere.

Comment: @Brilliand: "The party" is an ideological construct. It doesn't exist as such. Each person's understanding of what "the party" wants will be some variation of what *that person* wants (if they are a member) or a caricature of what they think the other side stereotypically wants (if they are a member of the opposite party).

Comment: @Kevin When bills receive a significant number of the opposing party's votes, they make a big deal about it, so there's no chance that it will go unnoticed. When they just say "bipartisan", they're just touting that it wasn't purely partisan.

Comment: @Kevin Huh? "The party" is either the Democratic or Republican party. And it's practically always clear which party is promoting any particular bill.

Comment: @Barmar: I never said otherwise, so I have no idea what you mean by that.

Comment: @Kevin While there's no technically correct way to divine what "the party" wants, it is nonetheless the sort of thing that an honest layperson can talk about without any difficulty.  It's a fuzzy judgment about a large group of people whose preferences are partially known.

Comment: @Brilliand: Ask Alexandria Ocasio Cortez and Nancy Pelosi what the Democratic Party "wants." Do you really think they're both going to agree with respect to every single bill on the legislative calendar? I find that hard to fathom.

Comment: @JaredSmith Yeah, that makes sense, I think I must have misunderstood what you said, but I can't remember how. It definitely is a form of "marketing"

Comment: I'm not a parliamentarian, but I remember reading somewhere that there's a procedure that can only be invoked if at least one member of your party voted a certain way.  I think this normally plays out as the minority party wants a bill to pass but knows they don't have the votes from the majority party, so they will have one member vote "no" so that procedure can be invoked later.

Comment: @Kevin You're thinking of a motion to reconsider. You can only move to reconsider a vote if you *personally* were on the winning side. If a vote will fail, one of the supporters will often switch their vote so that they can later move to reconsider.

Answer (score 15):

Any political move which is widely supported by the majority of both parties, is considered a bipartisan act.

The simple definition to the term "bipartisan" is "of 2 parties", that's all. The common use of this term, is when the issue is supported by the 2 "Parties", not even referring to individual persons of the party (see Merriam-Webster's definition).

However, some people can opt to use this term when there are a significant amount of people of the other party participating in the act. But when there are hardly a few, the use of this term seems like an appeal for undeserved credibility (I don't deny the obvious facts mentioned by Jontia)

Comment: I tend to agree with this response more, it is the way it should be. But what Jontia told was fact in today's political environment.

Comment: @dividbisan, I just searched a few news sites for articles containing the word "Bipartisan". In each and every single one of the examples given, the word Bipartisan was used in accordance with the abovementioned simple interpretation. I don't see bringing hundreds of search results, as suitable for this platform. You can choose to do your own search.

Comment: Sometimes the phrase 'broad bipartisan support' is used to distinguish this from a more superficial idea as described in Jontia's answer.

Comment: @Jacob3 It's fairly easy to find counterpoints. Trump's impeachment is described as "An Unusually Bipartisan Impeachment" at https://www.npr.org/2021/02/14/967807182/an-unusually-bipartisan-impeachment-vote-leaves-a-deeply-divided-nation and "an unusually bipartisan one" at https://www.nytimes.com/2021/01/14/briefing/impeachment-capitol-trump-china-who-wuhan.html as an example. A *majority* of Republicans were certainly not involved.

Comment: @ceejayoz, Thanks for your comment. The simple definition to the term "bipartisan" is "of 2 parties", that's all. The common use of this term, is when the issue is supported by the 2 "Parties", not even referring to individual persons of the party (see Merriam-Webster's definition). However, some people can opt to use this term when there are a significant amount of people of the other party participating in the act. But when there are hardly a few, the use of this term seems like an appeal for undeserved credibility (I don't deny the obvious facts mentioned by Jontia).

Comment: @JimmyJames Most often you hear that phrase in reference to the *voters*, not the politicians.  As in recently, *"The Covid stimulus bill had broad bipartisan support among voters, but still received zero Republican votes in the Senate"*

Comment: @DarrelHoffman A google search on the phrase shows it used with respect to party leadership as well.  And given that around half of the voters in the US identify as independent, I'm not sure it really means much when applied to voters.  In other words the people who really care about the partisan voter support are the politicians of the respective parties.

Comment: @JimmyJames I suppose it depends on what other questions they ask in the polls.  Is it (from most- to least- restrictive regarding independent voters): *"Which party are you registered with?" , "Which of the 2 major parties most closely aligns with your views?"*, or simply *"Who did you vote for in 2020?"*?

Comment: @DarrelHoffman I was basing my assertion off of [these results](https://news.gallup.com/poll/15370/party-affiliation.aspx) which upon reinspection doesn't really support what I wrote.  What does seem clear is that there's not a lot of stability there.  When I think of 'partisans' I have a sense of long-term consistent identification with a party but that may not be how it's generally understood.

Answer (score 4):

[Merriam-Webster defines bipartisan as "marked by or involving cooperation, agreement, and compromise between two major political parties".](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bipartisan) So a bipartisan bill is a bill where neither party has the required votes on its own (because some members of the majority party vote against the bill, or because the upper and lower house have a different majority party), but where the two parties together do have enough supporters of that bill to get it passed. Note that in case the upper and lower house have a different majority, every bill that passes both houses is by (this) definition bipartisan, but some bills that fail to pass both houses might still have passed one of the houses with bipartisan support.

If one of the parties has the numbers to push a bill through on its own, but a few members of the other party also vote for that bill, that's not typically considered bipartisan because such a bill required no compromise or cooperation with the other party. In the extreme case where almost everyone votes for a bill, that's most often called wide support and not usually described as bipartisan support either for the same reason (unless a serious effort has been done to get both parties on board, often for a symbolic reason).

Note that Merriam-Webster also includes the wider definition of "of, relating to, or involving members of two parties" which allows politicians to claim bipartisan support whenever any politician of another party is involved in a bill. But that's not the way people typically use the term.

Comment: I don't think anything in that definition requires a single party to not have the votes on its own. Something that passes with unanimous support from both sides would "marked by or involving cooperation, agreement, and compromise between two major political parties". I agree though that this probably fits a better ideal of bipartisanship, I just don't agree that this is how the word is actually used by politicians and journalists.

Comment: @jontia Good points.

Comment: @Jontia Depends a bit. If both parties work together to get something voted that's a compromise everyone can agree on, that would indeed be a bipartisan effort. If one party just pushes a bill declaring that kittens are cute, and the other party just votes for it because it's going to pass anyway and they don't want to be the anti-kitten party, that's hardly bipartisan. It might be spun that way of course, I can't deny that.

Comment: Nothing personal, but I routinely vote down answers that rely on the authority a dictionary definition over common usage. Dictionaries are *descriptive*, not prescriptive. People are the authority. Any human being who has seen it in use more than 10 times has far more info in their head about its meaning that can possibly fit in that one sentence, and could probably talk for at least 5 minutes about how its wrong or misleading.

Comment: @T.E.D. If you have another definition of "bipartisan" and think mine is wrong or misleading, feel free to explain why. However just downvoting with zero explanation is not constructive. Your dictionary rant is noted, but I'm not sure how it's relevant to my answer, as the dictionary definition I cited is exactly the same as the common usage of the word.

Comment: I don't think the dictionary definition supports this very limited view of bipartisanship - if even a single member of the opposite party votes for a bill, there is some level of "cooperation and agreement" between the two parties. I also don't see why a bill that *could* be passed by one party alone should be considered a partisan bill *regardless* of the support of the other party - with this definition, a partisan bill could become a bipartisan one by having *fewer* people support it, which strikes me as very odd.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie I wouldn't say a bill is either partisan or bipartisan. I would make a difference between a non-partisan bill, which is widely supported regardless of party allegiance, a partisan bill which is pushed by a single party, and a bipartisan bill which required active cooperation between two parties to accomplish.

When people talk about bipartisanship, what they're really asking for is cooperation over party lines (e.g. by centrists from both parties), they're not just asking that more utterly non-controversial bills get passed.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie I agree though that my definition feels slightly too narrow but I don't see an obvious improvement. Just saying that every bill that has at least one vote from every party is bipartisan seems like a very theoretical answer that doesn't correspond to what people perceive the term to mean in reality, but saying it requires wide support among both parties is also obviously wrong (if a few members of the majority party manage to drag a bill from the minority party through the Senate, that's obviously bipartisanship).

Comment: @FrederikVds: While people who hear the word "bipartisan" may expect that it describes actions which were not vehemently opposed by either party, people who favor a measure may describe it as "bipartisan" even if one of the parties is *almost* unanimously opposed to it.  Whether such a description is honest or dishonest is an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 4):

Here the term "bipartisan support" has several senses:

1. Aggregate bipartisan **congressional** support.  The two dominant parties, taken as a whole, mostly agree to support or not support some bill, law, rule, action, or principle.
2. Bilateral bipartisan **congressional** support.  Each of the two dominant parties, taken separately, and as a whole, mostly agree to support or not support some bill, law, rule, action, or principle.
3. Aggregate bipartisan **public** support.  Any statistical majority of voters from the two dominant parties mostly agree to support or not support some person, group, action, or system.
4. Bilateral bipartisan **public** support.  A statistical majority of voters from the two dominant parties, taken separately, and as a whole, mostly agree to support or not support some person, group, action, or system.

These four things are not the same.  For example, in 2021 USA there is [aggregate bipartisan public support for a $15 minimum wage](https://www.pewresearch.org/fact-tank/2019/07/30/two-thirds-of-americans-favor-raising-federal-minimum-wage-to-15-an-hour/); but there is not yet bilateral bipartisan congressional support.  Or to the contrary, Congress might have bilateral bipartisan support for some military action which the aggregate public does not support.

The term *bipartisan* is often used [equivocally](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivocation), to suggest the likelihood of one kind of (missing) support, when only some other kind is truly present.

Answer (score 0):

Since the United States has a two party system, "bipartisan support" requires "Yea" votes from members of both parties in order to qualify as bipartisan.  It only takes one vote.  For instance, in the recent vote on HR-1, the so called "For the People" bill, if one Republican had joined the Democrats in voting for the bill, it would have been considered a bipartisan bill.

Because the US has more than two parties, a bill could qualify as bipartisan if members of parties vote for a bill that normally caucus with one of the two dominant parties.  Bernie Sanders (I-VT) would qualify as a vote from the Democrat party, as an example.